# Forecast or Estimate Next Month Sales For Each Customer

Tags: excel, data-science, analytics, forecast

The problem statement that I am currently working on has data available for 27 customers and the purchase amount they have transacted on (in total) for each month in 2021 from Jan until Sept. The data looks like the attached image with this question/post.

[sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4jN0.png)

I could simply use average to find the next value but that'd not be precise to a very good extent, but then, in absence of any other data or features/columns, is that the only way to solve this question, or are there any other methods anyone can suggest? Note, both Excel &/or Python examples are fine.

Additional Note: I have already tried FORECAST functions in Excel, but I am not sure if the outcome is correct or not, since Microsoft documentation merely provides the formula by means of which this function performs the calculations. Overall there are 5 total types of FORECAST(.**) functions that Excel provides, but the documentation is poor, hence tomorrow, if I want to write the same solution in Python or any other programming language.

Comment: Excel has the forecast() function. Have you considered or tried that? I spent some time reading the Function Reference that came with Excel - back when it came on discs… Now you get the same online, but surprising what you can find if you read.

Comment: @SolarMike: Thanks for the suggestion; I have already tried this (should have mentioned in the question above), but I am not sure if the outcome is correct or not, since Microsoft documentation merely provides the formula by means of which this function performs the calculations. Overall there are 5 total types of FORECAST(.**) functions that Excel provides, but the documentation is poor, hence tomorrow, if I want to write the same solution in Python or any other programming language. Any suggestions please?

Comment: "Documentation is poir" no, just Excel is not designed to teach you maths, statistics or data analysis - you can get courses for that.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cursory glance at the data, there's a complexity that I'm missing like seasonality, trend, noise, outliers, etc., but let's just assume that this data is a simple trend line for each client.

From a purely high-level, excel can do a simple `FORECAST.ETS(target_date, values, timeline, [seasonality], [data_completion], [aggregation])` formula.

It can be streamlined with excel's built in data tool Forecast Sheet.

I could talk about Python but that's a little more hands on with a time series forecast.

Comment: Thanks ! This was a very good suggestion but I am not able to understand the underlying mathematics which Excel uses, hence even if we could use this built in function very easily, it still results into a black box solution. any suggestions? a more programmatic approach would be great.

Comment: I believe that excel's forecast function uses the Exponential Triple Smoothing (aka the Holt-Winters Exponential Smoothing) which is more robust than a simple moving average. It works well for time-series.